# Get the Object Index From ArrayList with JSTL

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

Is it possible to get the "row" index from an arraylist using JSTL?

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="contact">
<div style="padding: 5px;">
${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}
<br>
${contact.primaryPhone}
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

My intention is to set a hyperlink that contains each items ID on each row so the user can click and display a popup, or another page and easily retrieve just the single object from the arraylist without going back to the database and setting another session object etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `varStatus` attribute.

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="contact" varStatus="loop">
  <div style="padding: 5px;">
  ${loop.index} - 
  ${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}
  <br>
  ${contact.primaryPhone}
 </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution:

```
<c:set var="index" value="${0}"></c:set>
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="contact">
<div style="padding: 5px;">
${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}
<br>
${contact.primaryPhone}
<br>
${index}
</div>
<c:set var="index" value="${index+1}"></c:set>
</c:forEach>
```

If anyone knows a more elegant approach, I would be happy to see it.